# Class 'ZipArchive' not found en Cpanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-excel

Tengo este proyecto en laravel el cual baja un excel. En mi localhost funciona perfectamente pero en produccion me aparece este mensaje cuando intento bajar el excel a traves de la pagina web.

```
Class 'ZipArchive' not found
```

Comment: Suena a una librería que no está disponible en la instalación de producción, sea en el OS o la librería de PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione habilitando la extension ZIP en el PHP Selector del cpanel.

Comment: Podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada haciendo click en el check del costado de la respuesta :D Ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio :D